# Crash in ios app

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, reachability

I included crashlytics in my ios app and distributed it via enterprise. Crashlytics keeps on reporting below crash daily regarding Reachability. I googled, but didn't get what causing this crash.

```
    Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
-[__NSMallocBlock__ reachabilityChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c5cdfc0


Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x316642a3 __exceptionPreprocess + 162
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3252297f objc_exception_throw + 30
2  CoreFoundation                 0x31667e07 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 170
3  CoreFoundation                 0x31666531 ___forwarding___ + 392
4  CoreFoundation                 0x315bdf68 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
5  CoreFoundation                 0x315b5037 _CFXNotificationPost + 1426
6  Foundation                     0x3319ed91 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 72
7  Foundation                     0x331a2853 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:] + 30
8                                 0x0005aee9 ReachabilityCallback (Reachability.m:94)
9  SystemConfiguration            0x30f5f161 reachPerform + 924
10 CoreFoundation                 0x31639683 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
11 CoreFoundation                 0x31638ee9 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 212
12 CoreFoundation                 0x31637cb7 __CFRunLoopRun + 646
13 CoreFoundation                 0x315aaebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
14 CoreFoundation                 0x315aad49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
15 GraphicsServices               0x393a82eb GSEventRunModal + 74
16 UIKit                          0x38e662f9 UIApplicationMain + 1120
17                           0x00076f2f main (main.m:16)
18 libdyld.dylib                  0x350bab20 start
```

Comment: It seems that `reachabilityChanged` is called upon a class that doesn't provide this method. Most probable reason is that your class has been deallocated, but you haven't set your delegate to nil?

Comment: @gWiz But i am getting **"ARC forbids explicit message send of dealloc"** when i called [supder dealloc] inside -(void) dealloc{} metod

Comment: Under ARC you can provide an implementation of `dealloc` but within it you shouldn't call `[super dealloc]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're registering a reachability observer which is being deallocated but not removing itself as an observer before that happens. So, when the reachability notification is posted later it is sent to a deallocated instance (i.e. random memory location) and you get a crash.

All observers (whether of reachability or any other notification with `NSNotificationCenter`) should remove themselves as an observer before they are deallocated.

Comment: But i am getting **"ARC forbids explicit message send of dealloc"** when i called [supder dealloc] inside -(void) dealloc{} metod

Comment: Don't call super... (the compiler adds that for you)

Comment: I am using my own terminateNotification() method instead of **dealloc()**                                                           -(void) terminateNotification{
    [internetReach stopNotifier];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}                                                                            Is there any difference between dealloc() and terminateNotification()?

Comment: and what will call that?